# Code Explorer UI

Tags: c#, wpf, rubberduck, xaml

The third post in the Code Explorer series is about the UI and main VM.

This is the XAML, except a few hundred lines of styling:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Rubberduck.UI.CodeExplorer.CodeExplorerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:codeExplorer="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.Navigation.CodeExplorer"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI.Controls"
             xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI.Converters"
             ResxExtension.DefaultResxName="Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI" 
             Language="{UICulture}"
             Name="CodeExplorer"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance codeExplorer:CodeExplorerViewModel}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="RefreshImage" UriSource="../../Resources/arrow-circle-double.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="UndoImage" UriSource="../../Resources/arrow-circle-left.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="PrintImage" UriSource="../../Resources/printer.png" />

        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
        <converters:BoolToHiddenVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToHiddenVisibility" />
        <converters:InvertBoolValueConverter x:Key="InvertBoolValue" />

        <Style x:Key="ShinyTreeView"
               TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5"/>
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#adc6e5"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="500" />
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyleWithSignatures" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding NameWithSignature}" />
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding NameWithSignature}" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="500" />
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="TreeViewIconStyle" TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource IconStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding CollapsedIcon}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- thanks to H.B. on http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797323/1188513 -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ExpandedIcon}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="codeExplorer:CodeExplorerItemViewModel"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Style="{StaticResource TreeViewIconStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=DisplaySignatures, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenVisibility}}" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleWithSignatures}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=DisplaySignatures, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CodeExplorerTemplate" 
                                  DataType="codeExplorer:CodeExplorerProjectViewModel"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Style="{StaticResource TreeViewIconStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=DisplaySignatures, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenVisibility}}" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleWithSignatures}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=DisplaySignatures, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="64" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="48"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="#FFEEF5FD" />

        <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0" IsLocked="True">
            <ToolBar Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarWithOverflowOnlyShowingWhenNeededStyle}">

                <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
                    <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/arrow-circle-double.png" />
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=Refresh}" />
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>

                <Separator />

                <Menu>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=Add}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/plus-circle.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_AddTestModuleText}"
                                  Command="{Binding AddTestModuleCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_AddStdModuleText}"
                                  Command="{Binding AddStdModuleCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                        <MenuItem Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_AddClassModuleText}"
                                  Command="{Binding AddClassModuleCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                        <MenuItem Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_AddFormText}"
                                  Command="{Binding AddUserFormCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>

                <Separator />

                <Menu Margin="0,0,2,0">
                    <MenuItem Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_Sort}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/edit-list-order.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>

                        <MenuItem Name="SortByName"
                                  Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=SortStyle_ByName}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding SortByName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  Command="{Binding SetNameSortCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SortByName, Path=IsChecked}"
                                  IsCheckable="True" />
                        <MenuItem Name="SortBySelection"
                                  Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=SortStyle_BySelection}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding SortBySelection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  Command="{Binding SetSelectionSortCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SortBySelection, Path=IsChecked}"
                                  IsCheckable="True" />

                        <Separator />

                        <MenuItem Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=SortStyle_ByType}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding SortByType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  IsCheckable="True" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
                <ToggleButton Name="DisplaySignatures" IsEnabled="{Binding CanRefresh}" ToolTip="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_ShowSignaturesToolTip}" IsChecked="True">
                    <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/Microsoft/PNG/DisplayFullSignature_13393_32.png" />
                </ToggleButton>

                <Separator />

                <Button Command="{Binding OpenDesignerCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                    <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/Microsoft/PNG/VSProject_form.png" />
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_ShowDesignerToolTip}" />
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>

                <Separator />

                <Button Command="{Binding CopyResultsCommand}">
                    <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/document-copy.png" />
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_CopyToolTip}" />
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>

            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>

        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Background="White"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShinyTreeView}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_OnMouseDoubleClick"
                  Style="{StaticResource CodeExplorerTreeViewStyle}" BorderThickness="0,1">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <controls:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TreeView>

        <controls:BusyIndicator Grid.Row="1" Width="36" Height="36" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" Height="5" ShowsPreview="True" Cursor="SizeNS" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="DimGray">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MinHeight="48" Background="WhiteSmoke">

                <Grid Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Source="{Binding SelectedItem.CollapsedIcon}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding PanelTitle}" FontWeight="Bold"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>

                <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>

                <WrapPanel>
                    <controls:LinkButton Margin="4"
                            Visibility="{Binding CanExecuteIndenterCommand, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Command="{Binding IndenterCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                            Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=SmartIndenterMenu}" />
                    <controls:LinkButton Margin="4"
                            Visibility="{Binding CanExecuteRenameCommand, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                            Command="{Binding RenameCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                            Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=Rename}" />
                    <controls:LinkButton Margin="4"
                            Visibility="{Binding CanExecuteFindAllReferencesCommand, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                            Command="{Binding FindAllReferencesCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                            Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_FindAllReferencesText}" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
    private CodeExplorerViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as CodeExplorerViewModel; } }

private void TreeView_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewModel != null && ViewModel.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ViewModel.NavigateCommand.Execute(ViewModel.SelectedItem);
    }
}

private void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((TreeViewItem)sender).IsSelected = true;
}
```

And here is the main VM:

```
public sealed class CodeExplorerViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDisposable
{
    private readonly FolderHelper _folderHelper;
    private readonly RubberduckParserState _state;

    public CodeExplorerViewModel(FolderHelper folderHelper, RubberduckParserState state, List<ICommand> commands)
    {
        _folderHelper = folderHelper;
        _state = state;
        _state.StateChanged += ParserState_StateChanged;

        _refreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => _state.OnParseRequested(this),
            param => !IsBusy && _state.IsDirty());

        _refreshComponentCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_RefreshComponentCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _navigateCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_NavigateCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

        _addTestModuleCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddTestModuleCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _addStdModuleCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddStdModuleCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _addClassModuleCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddClassModuleCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _addUserFormCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddUserFormCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

        _openDesignerCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_OpenDesignerCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _renameCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_RenameCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _indenterCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_IndentCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

        _findAllReferencesCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_FindAllReferencesCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _findAllImplementationsCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_FindAllImplementationsCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

        _importCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_ImportCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _exportCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_ExportCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _externalRemoveCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_RemoveCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (_externalRemoveCommand != null)
        {
            _removeCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRemoveComand, _externalRemoveCommand.CanExecute);
        }

        _printCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_PrintCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

        _commitCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_CommitCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
        _undoCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_UndoCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

        _copyResultsCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_CopyResultsCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

        _setNameSortCommand = new DelegateCommand(param =>
        {
            SortByName = (bool)param;
            SortBySelection = !(bool)param;
        });

        _setSelectionSortCommand = new DelegateCommand(param =>
        {
            SortBySelection = (bool)param;
            SortByName = !(bool)param;
        });
    }

    private CodeExplorerItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public CodeExplorerItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            if (_selectedItem is CodeExplorerProjectViewModel)
            {
                var vbe = _selectedItem.GetSelectedDeclaration().Project.VBE;
                var project = vbe.VBProjects.Cast<VBProject>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.HelpFile == _selectedItem.GetSelectedDeclaration().Project.HelpFile);

                if (project != null)
                {
                    vbe.ActiveVBProject = project;
                }
            }

            // ReSharper disable ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
            OnPropertyChanged("CanExecuteIndenterCommand");
            OnPropertyChanged("CanExecuteRenameCommand");
            OnPropertyChanged("CanExecuteFindAllReferencesCommand");
            OnPropertyChanged("PanelTitle");
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            // ReSharper restore ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
        }
    }

    private bool _sortByName = true;
    public bool SortByName
    {
        get { return _sortByName; }
        set
        {
            if (_sortByName == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _sortByName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            ReorderChildNodes(Projects);
        }
    }

    private bool _sortBySelection;
    public bool SortBySelection
    {
        get { return _sortBySelection; }
        set
        {
            if (_sortBySelection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _sortBySelection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            ReorderChildNodes(Projects);
        }
    }

    private readonly ICommand _copyResultsCommand;
    public ICommand CopyResultsCommand { get { return _copyResultsCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _setNameSortCommand;
    public ICommand SetNameSortCommand { get { return _setNameSortCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _setSelectionSortCommand;
    public ICommand SetSelectionSortCommand { get { return _setSelectionSortCommand; } }

    private bool _sortByType = true;
    public bool SortByType
    {
        get { return _sortByType; }
        set
        {
            if (_sortByType != value)
            {
                _sortByType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                ReorderChildNodes(Projects);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string PanelTitle
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            if (SelectedItem is CodeExplorerProjectViewModel)
            {
                var node = (CodeExplorerProjectViewModel) SelectedItem;
                return node.Declaration.IdentifierName + string.Format(" - ({0})", node.Declaration.DeclarationType);
            }

            if (SelectedItem is CodeExplorerComponentViewModel)
            {
                var node = (CodeExplorerComponentViewModel) SelectedItem;
                return node.Declaration.IdentifierName + string.Format(" - ({0})", node.Declaration.DeclarationType);
            }

            if (SelectedItem is CodeExplorerMemberViewModel)
            {
                var node = (CodeExplorerMemberViewModel) SelectedItem;
                return node.Declaration.IdentifierName + string.Format(" - ({0})", node.Declaration.DeclarationType);
            }

            return SelectedItem.Name;
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedItem is ICodeExplorerDeclarationViewModel)
            {
                return ((ICodeExplorerDeclarationViewModel) SelectedItem).Declaration.DescriptionString;
            }

            if (SelectedItem is CodeExplorerCustomFolderViewModel)
            {
                return ((CodeExplorerCustomFolderViewModel) SelectedItem).FolderAttribute;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecuteIndenterCommand { get { return IndenterCommand.CanExecute(SelectedItem); } }
    public bool CanExecuteRenameCommand { get { return RenameCommand.CanExecute(SelectedItem); } }
    public bool CanExecuteFindAllReferencesCommand { get { return FindAllReferencesCommand.CanExecute(SelectedItem); } }

    private ObservableCollection<CodeExplorerItemViewModel> _projects;
    public ObservableCollection<CodeExplorerItemViewModel> Projects
    {
        get { return _projects; }
        set
        {
            _projects = new ObservableCollection<CodeExplorerItemViewModel>(value.OrderBy(o => o.NameWithSignature));

            ReorderChildNodes(_projects);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ParserState_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Projects == null)
        {
            Projects = new ObservableCollection<CodeExplorerItemViewModel>();
        }

        IsBusy = _state.Status == ParserState.Parsing;
        if (_state.Status != ParserState.Ready)
        {
            return;
        }

        var userDeclarations = _state.AllUserDeclarations
            .GroupBy(declaration => declaration.Project)
            .Where(grouping => grouping.Key != null)
            .ToList();

        if (userDeclarations.Any(
                grouping => grouping.All(declaration => declaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Project)))
        {
            return;
        }

        var newProjects = userDeclarations.Select(grouping =>
            new CodeExplorerProjectViewModel(_folderHelper,
                grouping.SingleOrDefault(declaration => declaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Project),
                grouping)).ToList();

        UpdateNodes(Projects, newProjects);

        Projects = new ObservableCollection<CodeExplorerItemViewModel>(newProjects);
    }

    private void UpdateNodes(IEnumerable<CodeExplorerItemViewModel> oldList,
        IEnumerable<CodeExplorerItemViewModel> newList)
    {
        foreach (var item in newList)
        {
            CodeExplorerItemViewModel oldItem;

            if (item is CodeExplorerCustomFolderViewModel)
            {
                oldItem = oldList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == item.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                oldItem = oldList.FirstOrDefault(i =>
                    item.QualifiedSelection != null && i.QualifiedSelection != null &&
                    i.QualifiedSelection.Value.QualifiedName.ProjectId ==
                    item.QualifiedSelection.Value.QualifiedName.ProjectId &&
                    i.QualifiedSelection.Value.QualifiedName.ComponentName ==
                    item.QualifiedSelection.Value.QualifiedName.ComponentName &&
                    i.QualifiedSelection.Value.Selection == item.QualifiedSelection.Value.Selection);
            }

            if (oldItem != null)
            {
                item.IsExpanded = oldItem.IsExpanded;

                if (oldItem.Items.Any() && item.Items.Any())
                {
                    UpdateNodes(oldItem.Items, item.Items);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ParserState_ModuleStateChanged(object sender, Parsing.ParseProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.State != ParserState.Error)
        {
            return;
        }

        var componentProject = e.Component.Collection.Parent;
        var projectNode = Projects.OfType<CodeExplorerProjectViewModel>()
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Declaration.Project == componentProject);

        if (projectNode == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        SetErrorState(projectNode, e.Component);

        if (_errorStateSet) { return; }

        // at this point, we know the node is newly added--we have to add a new node, not just change the icon of the old one.

        var folderNode = projectNode.Items.FirstOrDefault(f => f is CodeExplorerCustomFolderViewModel && f.Name == componentProject.Name);

        UiDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (folderNode == null)
            {
                folderNode = new CodeExplorerCustomFolderViewModel(projectNode, componentProject.Name,
                    componentProject.Name);
                projectNode.AddChild(folderNode);
            }

            var declaration = CreateDeclaration(e.Component);
            var newNode = new CodeExplorerComponentViewModel(folderNode, declaration, new List<Declaration>())
            {
                IsErrorState = true
            };

            folderNode.AddChild(newNode);

            // Force a refresh. OnPropertyChanged("Projects") didn't work.
            Projects = Projects;
        });
    }

    private Declaration CreateDeclaration(VBComponent component)
    {
        var projectDeclaration =
            _state.AllUserDeclarations.FirstOrDefault(item =>
                    item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Project &&
                    item.Project.VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>().Contains(component));

        if (component.Type == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule)
        {
            return new ProceduralModuleDeclaration(
                    new QualifiedMemberName(new QualifiedModuleName(component), component.Name), projectDeclaration,
                    component.Name, false, new List<IAnnotation>(), null);
        }

        return new ClassModuleDeclaration(new QualifiedMemberName(new QualifiedModuleName(component), component.Name),
                projectDeclaration, component.Name, false, new List<IAnnotation>(), null);
    }

    private void ReorderChildNodes(IEnumerable<CodeExplorerItemViewModel> nodes)
    {
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            node.ReorderItems(SortByName, SortByType);
            ReorderChildNodes(node.Items);
        }
    }

    private bool _errorStateSet;
    private void SetErrorState(CodeExplorerItemViewModel itemNode, VBComponent component)
    {
        _errorStateSet = false;

        foreach (var node in itemNode.Items)
        {
            if (node is CodeExplorerCustomFolderViewModel)
            {
                SetErrorState(node, component);
            }

            if (_errorStateSet)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (node is CodeExplorerComponentViewModel)
            {
                var componentNode = (CodeExplorerComponentViewModel) node;
                if (componentNode.GetSelectedDeclaration().QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Component == component)
                {
                    componentNode.IsErrorState = true;
                    _errorStateSet = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly ICommand _refreshCommand;
    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get { return _refreshCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _refreshComponentCommand;
    public ICommand RefreshComponentCommand { get { return _refreshComponentCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _navigateCommand;
    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get { return _navigateCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addTestModuleCommand;
    public ICommand AddTestModuleCommand { get { return _addTestModuleCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addStdModuleCommand;
    public ICommand AddStdModuleCommand { get { return _addStdModuleCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addClassModuleCommand;
    public ICommand AddClassModuleCommand { get { return _addClassModuleCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addUserFormCommand;
    public ICommand AddUserFormCommand { get { return _addUserFormCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _openDesignerCommand;
    public ICommand OpenDesignerCommand { get { return _openDesignerCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _renameCommand;
    public ICommand RenameCommand { get { return _renameCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _indenterCommand;
    public ICommand IndenterCommand { get { return _indenterCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _findAllReferencesCommand;
    public ICommand FindAllReferencesCommand { get { return _findAllReferencesCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _findAllImplementationsCommand;
    public ICommand FindAllImplementationsCommand { get { return _findAllImplementationsCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _importCommand;
    public ICommand ImportCommand { get { return _importCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _exportCommand;
    public ICommand ExportCommand { get { return _exportCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _removeCommand;
    public ICommand RemoveCommand { get { return _removeCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _printCommand;
    public ICommand PrintCommand { get { return _printCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _commitCommand;
    public ICommand CommitCommand { get { return _commitCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _undoCommand;
    public ICommand UndoCommand { get { return _undoCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _externalRemoveCommand;

    // this is a special case--we have to reset SelectedItem to prevent a crash
    private void ExecuteRemoveComand(object param)
    {
        var node = (CodeExplorerComponentViewModel) SelectedItem;
        SelectedItem = Projects.First(p => ((CodeExplorerProjectViewModel) p).Declaration.Project == node.Declaration.Project);

        _externalRemoveCommand.Execute(param);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_state != null)
        {
            _state.StateChanged -= ParserState_StateChanged;
            _state.ModuleStateChanged -= ParserState_ModuleStateChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty satisfied with this, but I'm sure there are things that could be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like this:

```
_refreshComponentCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_RefreshComponentCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_navigateCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_NavigateCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

_addTestModuleCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddTestModuleCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_addStdModuleCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddStdModuleCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_addClassModuleCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddClassModuleCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_addUserFormCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_AddUserFormCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

_openDesignerCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_OpenDesignerCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_renameCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_RenameCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_indenterCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_IndentCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

_findAllReferencesCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_FindAllReferencesCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_findAllImplementationsCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_FindAllImplementationsCommand>().FirstOrDefault();

_importCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_ImportCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_exportCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_ExportCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
_externalRemoveCommand = commands.OfType<CodeExplorer_RemoveCommand>().FirstOrDefault();
```

The use of `.FirstOrDefault` makes it look like `commands` could possibly have more than one instance of each command which, if that's the case, would indicate a bug with whoever is injecting that `List<ICommand>`, which could really be an `IReadOnlyList<ICommand>`, since you're iterating it multiple times, but you're not interested in adding or removing items.

Using `.SingleOrDefault` would not only better convey the idea that *it's only supposed to find one*, it would also throw an `InvalidOperationException` if that's not the case, and that would put a problem under the spotlight - a problem that may or may not exist right now, that using `FirstOrDefault` potentially hides.

---

When you're determining the `PanelTitle` value...

```
var node = (CodeExplorerMemberViewModel) SelectedItem;
return node.Declaration.IdentifierName + string.Format(" - ({0})", node.Declaration.DeclarationType);
```

You're using the `DeclarationType` enum's string representation, which is its name *as it appears in code*. This should be a localized string instead.

---

In `ExecuteRemoveCommand`, you're comparing `Project` objects:

```
SelectedItem = Projects.First(p => ((CodeExplorerProjectViewModel) p).Declaration.Project == node.Declaration.Project);
```

Comparing `VBProject` object instances like this is known to be unreliable, you should be comparing `ProjectId` values instead. And again, why `First` when you only expect to match one?

Answer (score 2):

You could demerge common setters of the TreeViewItemStyle into a base style:

```
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyleBase" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="500" />
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
    </Style>    

    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleBase}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyleWithSignatures" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleBase}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding NameWithSignature}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding NameWithSignature}" />
    </Style>
```